# Does $\pi_0$ commute with (homotopy) limits?

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Consider in the category sSet of simplicial sets, let $X$ be a $J$-indexed diagram in sSet ($J$ a small category), and for each $j\in J$, $X_j$ is a Kan complex, then do we have

> $\pi_0({\rm holim}_{j\in J} X_j)\xrightarrow{\cong}{\rm lim}_{j\in J} \pi_0(X_j)$?

I can show this for $J$ being the poset $\mathbb{N}^{\rm op}$ as one can replace the diagram in such a way that all the maps in the (replaced) diagram are fibration, due to its simple shape.

Is it true in general?

(For a Kan complex $K$, $\pi_0K$ is the [(reflexive) coequalizer](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflexive+coequalizer) of the two faces $K_1\to K_0$. Reflexive coequalizers in Set commute with finite products.)

Comment: It's not even true for your poset: look at the Kan complexes associated to chain complexes, and then $\lim^1$ gives an obstruction. For a simpler counterexample, contemplate the diagram $* \to BG \leftarrow *$.

Comment: Your simple counterexample is very nice, thanks! But I think my poset case is correct, we can use functorial factorization to get a fibrant object in the "tower" category, whose limit is (weakly equivalent to) the homotopy limit of the given sequence. And for a tower of fibration of fibrant simplicial sets (Kan complex), one can show the result using that a fibration is surjection on components (meaning that on each degree, a component of the source is mapped surjectively to a component of the target).

Comment: A fibration isn't necessarily a surjection on components.

Comment: I mean the image of a Kan fibration is a disjoint union of some components of the target. (Of course, the map from empty simplicial set to any simplicial set is a Kan fibration.)

Comment: Precisely, a Kan fibration f : X → Y of Kan complexes is surjective in each degree iff the induced map f∗ : π0(X) → π0(Y ) is surjective.

Comment: But you can't guarantee injectivity of $\pi_0(ho\lim) \to \lim \pi_0$, as you can get a contribution from $\lim^1\pi_1$.

Comment: I think use what I said above, for every "path" $[u_0, v_0]$ in the "base" with $u_1$ lying over $u_0$, and lifting property w.r.t. $d^1: \Delta^0\to\Delta^1$, this path can be lifted to one $[u_1, v_1]$ in the "total space" (considering the square formed by $d^1, u_0 , [u_0, v_0]$ and the given fibration). Doing this inductively giving an element in $({\rm lim}_nX_n)_1$ (an "edge" in the limit), connecting two given vertices, proving injectivity.

Comment: Look at an example of non-vanishing $lim^1$ and you'll see where you're going wrong.

Comment: e.g. \pi_0 of the inverse limit of degree 2 maps $S^1 \to S^1$ is like $\mathbb{Z}^{\wedge}_2/\mathbb{Z}$. (If you care about point-set topology, this weird space is connected but very not path connected. I think people call these "solenoids")

Comment: It is well known that even your example doesn't work. The Bousfiels-Kan spectral sequence describes exactly the failure in general of this isomorphism, as well as those for higher homotopy groups.

Comment: @Jon Pridham, Dylan Wilson, Kevin Carlson: I find in Goerss-Jardine VI.2. Milnor exact sequence, giving the precise result, thanks all of you!